# Преобразование string[] в int[] без LINQ \\ С#

Tags: c#, массивы, типы

Задача:
Необходимо уже имеющийся массив строк, конвертировать в тип int[], не используя LINQ.

Что было сделано:
Попробовал внести данные в новый массив, используя цикл for, но получил логическую ошибку, с выводом непонятных чисел.

Желательно с пояснением.
Заранее благодарю ;)

Код:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите строку с пробелами: ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] array = str.Split(' ');

        int[] number = new int[array.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: замените в первом цикле `str` на `array` и добавьте `int.Parse`

Comment: Скорректировал, спасибо. (Если парсировать переменную, тогда компилятор ругается на это следующим образом: невозможно преобразовать из "char" в "string".

Comment: Конвертировал через Convert.ToInt32, но ошибка с выводом цифр осталась

Comment: `str[i]` - Что вы здесь ожидаете? Допустим, человек написал `Привет мир!`, вы берете скажем, первую букву - `П` - это цифра? Также, зачем вам тогда разбитие (`string[] array = str.Split(' ');`), если вы дальше его не используете?

Comment: Мне необходим ответ, как перевести это в int[], остальную задачу я буду организовывать самостоятельно

Comment: Вам уже сказали в первом комментари, подумайте логически, что вы сейчас делаете в коде. Я вам дам наводку - вы перебираете строку, а не разбитый массив строк.

Comment: Преобразование string[] в int[] основано на обходе всех строк (цикл, linq) и преобразовании каждой string в int. И преобразование одной строки в одно число может делаться либо через Convert или TryParse - но вы почему-то пока не можете понять концепцию, поэтому у вас что-то не срастается и не получается. Просто решите для начала базовую задачу: как из ОДНОЙ строки получить число, а потом уже к массивам переходите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i])` здесь ошибка, надо вместо `str[i]`
использовать `array[i]`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите строку с пробелами: ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();

    string[] array = str.Split(' ');
    int[] numbers = new int[array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = int.Parse(array[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));
}
```